# What is the difference between llvm::Function.isDeclaration() and llvm::Function.isDeclarationForLinker()?

Tags: clang, llvm

I am using LLVM in my project.
What is the difference between  `llvm::Function.isDeclaration()` and `llvm::Function.isDeclarationForLinker()`?

Answer (score 0):

`isDeclarationForLinker` is either of:

1. A `GlobalValue` is a declaration
2. A `GlobalValue` has `AvailableExternallyLinkage`

I took this from the defintion of the `isDeclarationForLinker` function:

```cpp
bool isDeclarationForLinker() const {
  if (hasAvailableExternallyLinkage())
    return true;

  return isDeclaration();
}
```

[`ExternallyAvailableLinkage` means](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#linkage-types):

> Globals with “`available_externally`” linkage are never emitted into the object file corresponding to the LLVM module. From the linker’s perspective, an `available_externally` global is equivalent to an external declaration.

> They exist to allow inlining and other optimizations to take place given knowledge of the definition of the global, which is known to be somewhere outside the module.

> Globals with `available_externally` linkage are allowed to be discarded at will, and allow inlining and other optimizations. This linkage type is only allowed on definitions, not declarations.

Basically, the difference is that `isDeclaration` means no definition.
`isDeclarationForLinker` means, there is a definition but the code for the global won't be emitted